# How do I loop through each path from top to bottom in python?

Tags: python, list, maya

given a string of this

```
s='MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout|Custom'
```

what is the simplest way to get a list like this in python 2.7?

```
['MayaWindow','MayaWindow|toolBar2','MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout','MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14','MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout','MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout|Custom']
```

such as:

```
import re
for t in s.split('|'):
    print re.search(r'.*%s'%t,s).group()
```

but it will break if the some folder names in the path are not unique, eg

```
s='MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|formLayout14|Custom'

import re
for t in s.split('|'):
    print re.search(r'.*%s'%t,s).group()

MayaWindow
MayaWindow|toolBar2
MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout
MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|formLayout14
MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|formLayout14
MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|formLayout14|Custom
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
>>> [s.rsplit("|", i)[0] for i in range(s.count("|"), -1, -1)]
['MayaWindow',
 'MayaWindow|toolBar2',
 'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout',
 'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14',
 'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout',
 'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout|Custom']
```

Answer (score 2):

from Python 3.2, [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) allows us to avoid using indexing

```
from itertools import accumulate
s = 'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout|Custom'

new_list = list(accumulate(s.split('|'), lambda x,y: '|'.join((x,y))))

print(new_list)
```

produces

```
['MayaWindow', 'MayaWindow|toolBar2', 'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout', 'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14', 'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout', 'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout|Custom']
```

On the other hand, in Python 2 you can do something along the line

```
elements = iter(s.split('|'))
acc = next(elements)
new_list = [acc, ]
for el in elements:
    acc += '|'+el
    new_list.append(acc)

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thanks ! But how could I do this in python 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

Split it on the delimiter of interest and then loop through each slice size:

```
s = 'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout|Custom'
l = s.split('|')
new_list = [l[:idx] for idx in range(1, len(l)+1)]
```

Result:

```
>>> for item in new_list:
...     print(*item)
...
MayaWindow
MayaWindow toolBar2
MayaWindow toolBar2 MainShelfLayout
MayaWindow toolBar2 MainShelfLayout formLayout14
MayaWindow toolBar2 MainShelfLayout formLayout14 ShelfLayout
MayaWindow toolBar2 MainShelfLayout formLayout14 ShelfLayout Custom
```

Or if you want strings rather than `list`s, `join()` them back on the delimiter:

```
new_list = ['|'.join(l[:idx]) for idx in range(1, len(l)+1)]
```

Result:

```
>>> for item in new_list:
...     print(item)
...
MayaWindow
MayaWindow|toolBar2
MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout
MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14
MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout
MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|ShelfLayout|Custom
```